# Apache Hive on Yarn

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

As per my understanding from blogs, Yarn (mapred2) is faster or smarter than hadoop's mapreduce. If its true, is there way to configure Hive to use Yarn/Mapred2 without any complications to improve performance or to increase utilization of resources?

Comment: You need to install a version of Hive that supports hadoop2/Yarn. We have Hive 0.12 running on hadoop-2.2.0 cluster and there are noticeable perf improvements though this is anecdotal and we've not run any tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hive runs on Yarn's mapred out-of-the-box.

But running an old Hive on Yarn is not going to be a earth shattering experience, you'll measure probably the same times. What you want is to get latest Hive developments and improvements (eg. [ORC and Vectorization](http://www.slideshare.net/oom65/orc-andvectorizationhadoopsummit)), and perhaps try out running [Hive on Tez](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/tez/). I recommend reading about [Stinger](http://hortonworks.com/labs/stinger/) and go over this [deployment guide](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-LABS/Projects/Stinger/StingerTechnicalPreviewInstall.pdf).

Comment: In my testing experience, moving from Hadoop 1 to Hadoop 2 resulted in between 20% - 30% improvement. The improvements Remus mentions are much more substantial.